# How to determine approximate type of SMD Ferrite Chip

Tags: ferrite, ferrite-bead

I am reverse-engineering a device so that I can develop my own, compatible device.  There are a number of SMD Ferrite Chips (size 0603) inside.

A quick look at Digikey shows that there are almost 600 different size 0603 Ferrite Chips in stock and active.

I'm looking for guidance on how I can characterize the original parts and come up with a suitable alternative.  Measuring the DC resistance is easy.  But I'm not sure about the rest.

What approach might allow me to choose a suitable device?

[Edit]

This is for an interface to a digital walkie-talkie.  UHF band:  400 - 470 MHz.  Speaker & Mic connections are my main concern.

My first thought (after I posted my question) is to use a cheapie spectrum analyzer and signal generator and spot-check attenuation using the 50 Ohm input impedance of the spectrum analyzer.

I'm not sure what else I should be looking for..

Comment: Do you have access to a network analyzer?

Comment: What role are the ferrite beads doing? Power supply filtering in digital circuits, or is it a RF circuit?

Comment: Failing a network analyzer, got a spectrum analyzer with tracking generator?

Comment: Generally low mu ferrite is used for UHF and high mu for HF but it is used for DC filter and low impedance circuits where adding 50~500 Ohms is desired for immunity